# How do I add D3 to my multi-page html/htm on repl.it?

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I'm studying the freecodecamp.com course on Data Representation with D3, but I can't figure out how to add it to an HTML file I'm working on on repl.it. I can't find any information from google or the website, so I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: What is repl.it?

Comment: Trouble in what way? If you create a new Html/JS/CSS project on repl.it it has an example of including a js file in the default project. You can download the d3 lib locally and hit the add file button in the UI. Then you replicate the <script> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can add JavaScript libraries by using a `<script>` tag in HTML. In your particular case, you can add:

`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>`

to whatever HTML files use it, either in the `head` section or in the `body` section, before the other `script` tag. If you're using a different version of d3, you may need to change `d3.v6.min.js` to a different version number. Then you should be able to use `d3` in your js file.